# Stretchy Header with React Native (pull down in ScrollView and zoom top image)

Tags: react-native

With having React-Native, I would like to implement Stretchy header(pull down in ScrollView and zoom top image), mentioned in http://blog.matthewcheok.com/design-teardown-stretchy-headers/

Do we have plugin for this? If not, could you tell me how to implement this with React Native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement ScrollView's `onScroll` function, and detect its content offset.

And check https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-parallax-view for more details.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <Image style={{width:320,position:'absolute'}} />
  <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
    <HeaderView />
    <Components />
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Make the Image's position with 'absolute'.
Make the ScrollView's backgroundColor with 'transparent'.
And add a header view with a height equals to the Image's height to ScrollView.
Then comes your components.
And Animate is optional.

Comment: Thanks, KChen.  OK, I can use onScroll and detect the offset. How can I implement the zooming and sticking image on top?

Comment: @shohey1226 A simple way is to change the Image's style with different widths and heights according to content offsets, and set its resizeMode to 'stretch'.

Comment: @shohey1226 Show me the screenshot? A simple way is to set its positon with "absolute". But most time it sticks to top...

Comment: I can pull down but there are space between image and top. `position: 'absolute'` is not working...  screenshot - https://47eb63ce0b30e2d345f2645d0b43895404ad8ee2.googledrive.com/host/0ByjmebLQ0XebdVdNU2FDZjV1cVE

Comment: The above screenshot is the middle of pulling down, which makes the image bigger... also, I'm using https://github.com/nick/react-native-carousel for the horizontal image scroll.

Comment: Thanks. I can do zoom and sticking to top, however,  I can not pull down on the image. Only can pull down on ScrollView area..

Comment: Maybe there is some trouble. See my answer.

Comment: @shohey1226 Good News! https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-parallax-view may be what you are looking for !

Comment: Yup, this is what I was looking for.  I checked the code, which used Animated component but the idea is your option1. To use  carousel(horizontal scroll) on the top image requires more deep implementation, like to detect gesture x axis or y axis but I will dig into later this. Anyway, many thanks for your help.  Could you update with the module on your answer so that I can mark resolved with yours?